# How to create woocommerce order from other wordpress site

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I created a action hook on order created using woocommerce_checkout_create_order hook. But it returns internal server error with:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null
```

Below is my code:

```
function passorder( $customer_id, $order_id ) {
   $gogo_ck = 'ck_86b1d98af2e5afd483eeb12bb0df9c3da63b6eab';
   $gogo_cs = 'cs_19c4c25423925809b1a2377b028fbf10d0eb50c6';
   $live_url = 'https://gogopasar.vxstep.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=' . $gogo_ck . '&consumer_secret=' . $gogo_cs;
   $customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
   $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order_data= $order->get_data();
   $body = array(
      'status' => 'completed',
      'meta_data' => array( array( 
         'key' => 'createdby',
         'value' => 'luqmantest'
      )),
      'total' => 0,
      'billing' => array(
         'first_name' => $order_data->get_billing_first_name(),
         'email' => $order_data->get_email(),
      ),
      'line_items' => array( array( 
         'product_id' => 2995,
         'quantity' => 1,
      )),
   );
   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url, 
      array(
         'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
         'timeout' => 30,                    
         'body' => json_encode( $body ),
      )
   );
}
What i want to achieve is when order is created, it will be created in other wordpress site also.
Using import and export is time-consuming.
```

Comment: You already have $order_id then you have this $order_id = $order->get_id() which is wrong since $order is not defined yet. Swap the order of both rows.

Comment: Previously the $order_id definition is not there, i'm using the $order_id pulled from the parameter but i'm not sure if the $order_id from the parameter is there. Is there a liost to see what variable can be called globally?